# Confusing Java parameter manipulation

Tags: java

When I'm using a=x, b=y the result is 15. But when I'm using x=a,y=b, the result is 0. Could you please explain why?

```
public class Test {
        int a , b;

    Test(int x, int y) {    

         a=x;

         b=y;

    }

    int sr() {

        return a*b;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Test t=new Test(5,3);

        System.out.println(t.sr());
    }

}
```

Comment: Step one: Format your code legibly. (I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=x;

b=y;
```

will set the instance attributes `a` & `b` values with the passed values `x` and `y`. so when you create an instance using :

```
Test t=new Test(5,3);
```

a and b will be have values 5 & 3 respectively. Hence calling method `t.sr` will return

```
a*b = 5*3 = 15;
```

On the other hand if u use:

```
x = a;

y = b;
```

local variables x and y will be set to with the default values of a and b i.e. 0. Also a and b will hold defualt values as 0 as no other value is set. So when u do

```
 Test t=new Test(5,3);
```

as a & b have values 0 so calling method `t.sr` will return

```
a*b = 0*0 = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

The default values for int fields is 0. So if you do not assign a value to them they are 0.
See: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14

Comment: Actually, `a` and `b` are not initialised at all. (...if I could -1 this more than once...)

Comment: +1 @icedwater: Since this is Java, `a` and `b` __are__ initialized to `0` when the instance is created by the JVM. It's just that the constructor is not explicitly assigning another value to them.

Comment: I rewrote my answer. See the JLS.

Comment: Well then, that shows you how much I know about Java. But now at least we have a better explanation. Sorry /morpheus05 and thanks @Sebastian.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you are passing the value of **x and y** and storing it in **a and b** respectivey. Now when you call method **a and b** has got values so it returns the value of `a*b`.
**Also a and b are class variables so it has got default values i.e a=0,b=0;**
Now in the second case **x=a,y=b**. you are storing the values of **a and b respectivey in x and y**.As you are not storing the any values in a and b and again you are calling sr method so it only returns value of a and b i.e `0*0` so you get 0 as output

Answer (score 1):

when you use 
x= a, y=b

you are not assigning  values to a and b which was used in sr().

Since there are instance variable they will be assigned default value 0 and hence result is 0

Answer (score 1):

when you use 
x=a, y=b 
**x and y are local variables**. They are discard as soon as that block(constructor) get executed.
But **a, b are instance variables**. They exist until you have the instance from the class. Default value for int instances is 0;
since you are not changing those values you always get 0

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the constructor, `x and y` are local variables.

If you do:

```
x = a;
y = b;
```

The member variables `a and b` are never initialized in your constructor. So doing a `a * b` will yield 0 as the default values for `a and b` is 0.

And really, it makes no sense to do `x = a` and `y = b`.